# Jquery excracting json representations {41: Array[2], 42: Array[1]}

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, undefined

I have the following response from a Ajax call which is this 
{41: Array[2], 42: Array[1]} Its basically a python dictionary sent back from a server that looks like this:  `{41: [0:15740, 1:15741], 42: [0:15744]}`

So in Jquery I need to be able to get the keys and matching values that are stored within this json representation and be able to display them in an alert. This is the code I have so far but it keeps coming up as data.length: undefined although it does log the data in the line before.

```
$.ajax({
    url: target,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(myData),
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log('done:', data);
    console.log('data.Length : :', data.length);

    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
        spreadsheet = data[x].Id;

        spreadsheet += "<br>";
        spreadsheet += data[x].Name;
        spreadsheet += "<br>";
        console.log('Spreadsheet : ' + spreadsheet)
    }
})
```

Comment: use `console.log('data.Length : :'+ data.length); `

Comment: Just tried it there and its giving the same 'undefined'

Comment: what is the output in `console.log(data);`

Comment: This is what I have in data {41: [0:15740, 1:15741], 42: [0:15744]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the response is JSON, you first need to parse it.

```
data=JSON.parse(data)
```

Then you need to iterate over the object like this

```
for(var key in data) 
{// do stuff here
//you can access the array like this
data[key][0]
//or you can further iterate over the array
for(var x=0; x<data[key].length; x++)
{
//now you can access array element like 
//this
data[key][x]
}
}
```

Edit: Since the response is not json you don't need the  statement.

> **JSON.parse(data)**

```
for(var key in obj) 
{// do stuff here
var elem;
//or you can further iterate over the array
for(var x=0; x<obj[key].length; x++)
{
//now you can access array element like
//this
console.log(obj[key][x].slice(2));
 elem=obj[key][x].slice(2);//now elem will contain the values 15740,15741
//,15744
}
```

Comment: When I try data=JSON.parse(data); I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o”

Comment: console.log('done:', data). Paste the output of this statement in comments.

Comment: I have read your comment below and what you are receiving is not json. And secondly the syntax is illegal since you can not have named keys in javascript arrays. Do a simple test, assign the data variable to another variable and check if there is an error thrown in the console.

Comment: And as far as python is concerned. It is not possible to have keys inside a list. It is a a syntax error. You can not have `[0:15740, 1:15741]`.

Comment: Well Im not sure if they are in a list or quotes or what I am just expanding them in the console window so I don't actually know what they are in.

Comment: If they are in quotes try the above code and tell me if it works. Skip the line that says JSON.parse(data). And inside the nested loop log `data[key][x]` to the console.

Comment: There are two possibilities either the whole response is a string then when you log it the console you should see something like this `"{41: [0:15740, 1:15741], 42: [0:15744]}"` or `"{41: ['0:15740', '1:15741'], 42: ['0:15744']}"`. Otherwise just the list items are strings then you should see this `Object {41: Array[2], 42: Array[1]}`. Now what exactly is being logged? Paste it here with the quotes.

Comment: This {41: Array[2], 42: Array[1]} Then when you expand it you can see the values

Comment: And are the values as following
`41: Array[2]0: 
     "0:15740"1: 
      "1:15741"`
or something else kindly post that as well.

Comment: I tried the code above. Now it is getting somewhere. I logged x in the outsid loop and bottom loop and got the following undefined manage_spreadsheets:2330:2
Array [ 15740 ] manage_spreadsheets:2331:2
Array [ 15741 ] manage_spreadsheets:2331:2
undefined manage_spreadsheets:2330:2
Array [ 15744 ]

Comment: Expand the object and kindly post the values that you see for key 41 and 42. Like this `41: Array[2]0: "0:15740"1: "1:15741"` and `42: Array[1]0: "0:15744"`

Comment: 41: Array[2]0: "0:15740" 1"0:15741" and 42: Array[1]0: "0:15744"

Comment: That's fantastic I can work with this now Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here data might be an object. Try using for--in e.g. for(var x in data) instaed of for loop. It might solve your issue.

```
 for (var x in data) {
        spreadsheet = data[x].Id;

        spreadsheet += "<br>";
        spreadsheet += data[x].Name;
        spreadsheet += "<br>";
        console.log('Spreadsheet : ' + spreadsheet)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
var obj = data;

jQuery.each(Object.keys(obj), function(i, x){
  spreadsheet = data[x].Id;

  spreadsheet += "<br>";
  spreadsheet += data[x].Name;
  spreadsheet += "<br>";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

please convert to Json format if the 'data' value received is string

```
var jsonData= JSON.parse(data) //if 'data' is string type.
```

Please share the type data or some sample part of the data you are receiving.

Comment: When I try data=JSON.parse(data); I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o”  {41: [0:15740, 1:15741], 42: [0:15744]}

Comment: Please provide few data value, so that i could find the exact problem. like {"41":"value", "42":{"a":"b"}}

Comment: {41: [0:15740, 1:15741], 42: [0:15744]}

Comment: You can't get length from these object, since it is not an java-script array list. so you can only use for loop like below                                                                                           for(var i in data){
    
    }

Comment: Before that please do "data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))" and the try for each